# Spark: Group RDD by id

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, rdd

I have a 2 RDDs. In Spark scala, how do I join event1001RDD and event2009RDD if they have the same id?

val event1001RDD: schemaRDD = [eventtype,id,location,date1]

```
[1001,4929102,LOC01,2015-01-20 10:44:39]
[1001,4929103,LOC02,2015-01-20 10:44:39]
[1001,4929104,LOC03,2015-01-20 10:44:39]
```

val event2009RDD: schemaRDD = [eventtype,id,date1,date2]

```
[2009,4929101,2015-01-20 20:44:39,2015-01-20 20:44:39]
[2009,4929102,2015-01-20 15:44:39,2015-01-20 21:44:39]
[2009,4929103,2015-01-20 14:44:39,2015-01-20 14:44:39]
[2009,4929105,2015-01-20 20:44:39,2015-01-20 20:44:39]
```

The expected result would be: (unique) (sorted by id)

[eventtype,id,1001's location,1001's date1,2009's date1,2009's date2]

```
2009,4929101,NULL,NULL,2015-01-20 20:44:39,2015-01-20 20:44:39
1001,4929102,LOC01,2015-01-20 10:44:39,2015-01-20 15:44:39,2015-01-20 21:44:39
1001,4929103,LOC02,2015-01-20 10:44:39,2015-01-20 14:44:39,2015-01-20 14:44:39
1001,4929104,LOC03,2015-01-20 10:44:39,NULL,NULL
2009,4929105,NULL,NULL,2015-01-20 20:44:39,2015-01-20 20:44:39
```

Note that for id 4929102, 1001 is used as the eventtype. 2009 eventtype would only be used if it does not have any matching id in 1001.

It can be RDD[String] - flat. or RDD Tuple via aggregateByKey. I just need to iterate over the RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of Full outer join. Here you go...

```
d1=[[1001,4929102,"LOC01","2015-01-20 10:44:39"],[1001,4929103,"LOC02","2015-01-20 10:44:39"],[1001,4929104,"LOC03","2015-01-20 10:44:39"]]
d2=[[2009,4929101,"2015-01-20 20:44:39","2015-01-20 20:44:39"],[2009,4929102,"2015-01-20 15:44:39","2015-01-20 21:44:39"],
    [2009,4929103,"2015-01-20 14:44:39","2015-01-20 14:44:39"],[2009,4929105,"2015-01-20 20:44:39","2015-01-20 20:44:39"]]

d1RDD = sc.parallelize(d1).map(lambda t: Row(d1_eventtype=t[0],d1_id=t[1],d1_location=t[2],d1_date1=t[3]))
d2RDD = sc.parallelize(d2).map(lambda t: Row(d2_eventtype=t[0],d2_id=t[1],d2_date1=t[2],d2_date2=t[3]))
d1DF = ssc.createDataFrame(d1RDD)
d2DF = ssc.createDataFrame(d2RDD)
print d1DF.printSchema()
print d2DF.printSchema()
d1DF.show()
d2DF.show()
d1DF.registerTempTable("d1")
d2DF.registerTempTable("d2")
res = ssc.sql("select case when d1.d1_eventtype is not null then d1.d1_eventtype else d2.d2_eventtype end et, \
                      case when d1.d1_id is not null then d1.d1_id else d2.d2_id end id, \
                      d1.d1_location loc, d1.d1_date1, d2.d2_date1, d2.d2_date2 \
                 from d1 full outer join d2 on d1.d1_id=d2.d2_id order by d1.d1_id")
res.show()
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- d1_date1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d1_eventtype: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d1_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d1_location: string (nullable = true)

None
root
 |-- d2_date1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d2_date2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d2_eventtype: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d2_id: long (nullable = true)

None
d1_date1            d1_eventtype d1_id   d1_location
2015-01-20 10:44:39 1001         4929102 LOC01      
2015-01-20 10:44:39 1001         4929103 LOC02      
2015-01-20 10:44:39 1001         4929104 LOC03      
d2_date1            d2_date2            d2_eventtype d2_id  
2015-01-20 20:44:39 2015-01-20 20:44:39 2009         4929101
2015-01-20 15:44:39 2015-01-20 21:44:39 2009         4929102
2015-01-20 14:44:39 2015-01-20 14:44:39 2009         4929103
2015-01-20 20:44:39 2015-01-20 20:44:39 2009         4929105
et   id      loc   d1_date1            d2_date1            d2_date2           
2009 4929101 null  null                2015-01-20 20:44:39 2015-01-20 20:44:39
2009 4929105 null  null                2015-01-20 20:44:39 2015-01-20 20:44:39
1001 4929102 LOC01 2015-01-20 10:44:39 2015-01-20 15:44:39 2015-01-20 21:44:39
1001 4929103 LOC02 2015-01-20 10:44:39 2015-01-20 14:44:39 2015-01-20 14:44:39
1001 4929104 LOC03 2015-01-20 10:44:39 null                null
```

Comment: Hi ayan, I need to update the sql since I have 3 RDDs now, can you look at it too? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472975/spark-group-rdd-sql-query